# SQL server database query webservice

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services

I have the following web method codes to retrieve the following:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Hawker> retrievehawker()
{
    List<Hawker> retrievehawker = new List<Hawker>();

    string qry = @"select hawkername, address, postal, xcoord, ycoord, popularity from uploadphoto";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = qry;

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        Hawker retrieveHawker = new Hawker();
        retrieveHawker.hawkername = Convert.ToString(mySqlDataReader["hawkername"]);
        retrieveHawker.address = Convert.ToString(mySqlDataReader["address"]);
        retrieveHawker.postal = Convert.ToString(mySqlDataReader["postal"]);
        retrieveHawker.xcoord = Convert.ToDouble(mySqlDataReader["xcoord"]);
        retrieveHawker.ycoord = Convert.ToDouble(mySqlDataReader["ycoord"]);
        retrieveHawker.popularity = Convert.ToDouble(mySqlDataReader["popularity"]);


        retrievehawker.Add(retrieveHawker);
    }
    mySqlDataReader.Close();
    conn.Close();
    return retrievehawker;
}
```

How can I change the code so that whenever this method is triggered by my windows phones, it will insert +1 to the value of popularity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call below method to update the popularity

```
int SetPopularity()
{
    string qry = @"update uploadphoto set popularity=popularity+1";    
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(qry,con);  
    conn.Open();
    int status=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    return status;
}
```

Comment: How can i call this method inside my retrieve hawker ? I have to based on a selection and do the update

Comment: if possible check out this question i asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362197/sql-server-retrieve-and-update-windows-phone-7