# sql server retrieve and update (windows phone 7)

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-phone-7

I have a retrieve code of:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Hawker> retrievehawker()
{
    List<Hawker> retrievehawker = new List<Hawker>();

    string qry = @"select hawkername, address, postal, xcoord, ycoord, popularity from uploadphoto";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = qry;

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        Hawker retrieveHawker = new Hawker();
        retrieveHawker.hawkername = Convert.ToString(mySqlDataReader["hawkername"]);
        retrieveHawker.address = Convert.ToString(mySqlDataReader["address"]);
        retrieveHawker.postal = Convert.ToString(mySqlDataReader["postal"]);
        retrieveHawker.xcoord = Convert.ToDouble(mySqlDataReader["xcoord"]);
        retrieveHawker.ycoord = Convert.ToDouble(mySqlDataReader["ycoord"]);
        retrieveHawker.popularity = Convert.ToDouble(mySqlDataReader["popularity"]);


        retrievehawker.Add(retrieveHawker);
    }
    mySqlDataReader.Close();
    conn.Close();
    return retrievehawker;
}
```

and a setpopularity of :

```
    [WebMethod]
public int SetPopularity()
{
    string qry = @"update uploadphoto set popularity=popularity+1";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = qry;
    conn.Open();
    int status = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    return status;
}
```

How can I combine them together so that based on a selection of a place in the windows phone 7, of a button click, then it will trigger the setpopularity. Right now the code for set popularity is adding the whole column of +1 to popularity. Help please.

Comment: The answer lies in the [WHERE clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Comment: set popularity=popularity+1 where hawkername ? Hawker retrieveHawker = new Hawker();
        retrieveHawker.hawkername = Convert.ToString(mySqlDataReader["hawkername"]); ?

Comment: If hawkername is your primay key then yes, you need to keep your photo linked to this primary key value and use it to update just that record

Comment: my primary key is id, but I can use hawkername as primary also, I will try what you say first. Hoping others can help me out too.

Comment: well, I would prefer to use a primary key because it is highly improbable that this could change in future, but if hawkername has an UNIQUE index associated then it is good. (Remember that PK have automatically indexes for fast retrivial)

Comment: Regarding the question you just deleted, why would you delete it after three minutes, instead of giving someone a chance to answer? I was halfway through a pretty substantial answer and the question got ripped out from under me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass to your `SetPopularity` method the primary key (or another unique value) of your photo table.
In that way you could change your sql command to update only the record required

```
[WebMethod]
public int SetPopularity(string hawkername)
{
    string qry = @"update uploadphoto set popularity=popularity+1 
                   WHERE hawkername=@hawk";
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hawk", hawkername);
        int status = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return status;
     }
}
```

The string passed to the method is your primary key (or an unique value better if indexed) and could be used in the WHERE clause.
Notice also the using statement around the disposable objects and the parameterized query approach to avoid Sql Injections and parsing problems.